# Deriving $\frac{8}{\sqrt{x-2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm not sure how to derive this:

$$\frac{8}{\sqrt{x-2}}$$

---

I tried

$$8 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}}$$

$$8 \cdot (\sqrt{x-2})^{-1}$$

Differentiating w.r.t. $x$,

$$8 \cdot -1 \cdot (\sqrt{x-2})^{-2}$$

$$8 \cdot -1 \cdot \frac{1}{(\sqrt{x-2})^{2}}$$

$$\frac{-8}{(\sqrt{x-2})^{2}}$$

$$\frac{-8}{x-2}$$

But the answer is

$$\frac{-4}{(x-2)\sqrt{x-2}}$$

---

What should I have done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\dfrac{8}{\sqrt{x-2}} = 8\cdot (x-2)^{-1/2}$.

Now you can use $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x^n) = n x^{n-1}$, where $n = -1/2$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d(f(g(x)))}{dx}\ne f'(g(x))\quad\text{instead}\quad \frac{d(f(g(x)))}{dx}= f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
So
$$(f(\sqrt{x-2}))'=f'(\sqrt{x-2})(\sqrt{x-2})'=f'(\sqrt{x-2})\frac1{2(\sqrt{x-2})}$$
When $f(x)=8/x$ then $f'(x)=-8/x^2$
$$f'(\sqrt{x-2})=\frac{-8}{(\sqrt{x-2})^2}\frac1{2(\sqrt{x-2})}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$, then $$\frac{8}{\sqrt{x-2}}=\frac{0-8(\sqrt{x-2})'}{x-2}=\frac{-4\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2}}}{x-2}=-\frac{4}{(x-2)\sqrt{x-2}}.$$